# Edited: Jquery animation working with 1 div, with 2 divs but strange behaviour with 3 or more

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/cwfgvbzh/2/

As you can see there are 2 div containers with class "subbanner". As soon as you add a third, fourth or more, the animation will become very weird.

You can take out line 64 and 65 in the JS and then it will run smoothly:

```
      opacity: 1, // if you take these
      height: "110px" // out, it will work
```

Can anyone see a reason for this?

I know animations can be just queued without all the callbacks but if you do that then the animations will all be out of sync once you minimize/maximize the browser or you go to a different tab for a while.

---

**Edit: I took out the majority of the code to make it easier.**

http://jsfiddle.net/cwfgvbzh/3/

As you can see (I hope) the animations have varying delays when they should animate for 300ms every 2seconds.

Is that a resource issue (processor, ram?) or is there an error in my code?

Comment: Are you serious with these tons of `$(this).prev()` and `$(this).next()` functions? And if there are 10 same steps, will you write even more code?

Comment: spageti code everwhere

Comment: Instead of prev and next I could also write "class xyz", "class abc" all the time but that creates a lot more code if you have 30 "subbanner" divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the multiple calls to `.animate()` are building up a queue. With only two containers the animation cycles ends fast and the queues are cleared fast, so you don't notice any problems.

However, with more elements animated you have longer animation cycles and your `setInterval()` keeps animating, so you end up with multiple parallel queues all trying to animate the same elements at different points in time.

One solution to the problem is call `.stop()` before every `.animate()` on your code. This will cease any animation on the element before starting a new one, preventing the queue. However, as pointed out on [this](https://css-tricks.com/full-jquery-animations/) article, this will also prevent the animation to complete it's full cycle.

So the best approach is to only starting a new animation if the element is no longer being animated. As also pointed out on the article, use `.filter(':not(:animated)').animate()` and you no longer have to worry with queues.

Here's the updated fiddle with that approach: http://jsfiddle.net/c89potv0/

PS.: One thing I noticed is that if you change tabs on the browser and come back after a while, the animation will act funky again. This is probably because of how the browser handles the javascript threads on each tab. But since the code is now only applying animations on non-animated elements only, the animation will fix itself after a few seconds.